# no_translation error while attempting to write unicode characters to file in Elixir

Tags: unicode, erlang, elixir, latin1

I have a stream that I'm reading from and in turn am writing to a file however I am getting an error that is caused by the presence of a `’`. I assume this is because I'm opening the file w/ the wrong encoding or something but I don't know how to properly set it:

```
file = File.open!("/some/path.csv", [:write])
IO.write(file, "’")
```

This results in the following error:

> ** (ErlangError) erlang error: :no_translation                                                                (stdlib) :io.put_chars(#PID<0.250.0>, :unicode, "’")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should open the file in `:utf8` mode.

```
file = File.open!("/tmp/foo.txt", [:write, :utf8])
IO.write(file, "’")
```